# redis key value not available for subsequent requets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redis

I am making two ajax calls in my rails application, 1st ajax call saves a key value pair on redis and see that the value is saved correctly.

But the next ajax call i make and try to retrieve the key i dont get the desired value.

I am setting the value like

> $redis.setnx("#{id}_number,"10")

and trying to get the value like

> $redis.get("#{id}_number") is returning nil

not sure what am i doing wrong, any help would be appriciated. Thanks.

Comment: There is a typo in `$redis.setnx("#{id}_number,"10")`. Is this the actual code or just in this question?

Comment: Hello there, what typo is it? Thanks

Comment: You have one quote missing, the correct syntax is `$redis.setnx("#{id}_number", "10")`

Comment: Hello loqman, actually this is a example, but you were rite it was a typo. You want to add it as a answer i will accept it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one quote missing, the correct syntax is `$redis.setnx("#{id}_number", "10")`